# How to change my IE start page back?

Tags: windows, internet-explorer, windows-registry

In my registry, the entry "Start Page" under [HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Microsoft\Internet Explorer\Main] was changed to some bad url. And I found that i don't have permission to modify the [HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Microsoft\Internet Explorer\Main], only got a "everyone" user to access it. I cannot modify any entry below it even as an Admin. 
Could anyone help? Thanks.

Comment: What version of Windows, and are you logged in as an administrator account?

Comment: This sounds like a nasty problem...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'd check my computer with "HijackThis" and let someone review the logfile (there are special websites / forums for this). I once had a similar problem (DNS/gateway settings were changed and I couldn't change them back, no matter what I tried), and the only fix was a series of running different spyware-cleaners and rebooting Windows a couple of times in safe mode during the process ...

http://free.antivirus.com/hijackthis/

Answer (score 0):

Ineed some kind of antivirus should be installed, for example Avira Antivir to remove the malware that changed the value int he first place.

Otherwise maybe UAC is enabled and limiting your privileges?